# Severe echo problem on GooVe IP Lite

Tags: voip

Since my Google Hangout doesn't work, I tried Goove IP Lite with ring.to. There is severe echo problem, however, whether I check "Basic Echo Canceler" or "Adaptive Echo Canceler" with "Post Processing" and "Auto Detect" "Echo Tail". Is there some way to solve the echo problem? What other VoIP app (free or cheap) are worth trying? I am using Android 4.4.2 on Kyocera Hydro Icon.

Comment: You could try Viber, good rating on the Play store or Skype with only voice calls. Even WhatsApp and Messenger by facebook let you call, but in my experience they have a bad audio quality. The echo problem is probably due to the app you are using. If normal phone calls work good, then it should be the app and not a hardware issue. That's all I know, I'm sorry.

Comment: Skype isn't free for making calls in US. How about Viber, WhatsApp and facebook Messenger?

Comment: Of those three the best is probably Viber. I don't know of any cost to use it, except for the eventual data usage of course.